# android checking if app has been opened multiple days in a row

Tags: android, date

I am trying to implement a feature which detects if the user has been on the app for 2, 3, 4.... days in a row. I am trying to think about how this would work but I am struggling, hence I need help.

Originally, I thought about getting the date, adding that to an array and then checking the last few entries of the array were in a row. For example [28, 29, 30]. This would return a message of value saying the user had visited the app 3 days in a row. The issue with this is when I overlap and go into a new month. For example [38, 29, 30, 1]. My solution will no longer work.

I am looking for a solution which gets around this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just increment a number stored in SharedPreferences?

Comment: just store the current Day of year i shared preferences and a counter of days consecutively app opened and compare the saved day in preferences on next run if day saved in shared preferences is 1 less then current day of year increment counter and save the new date and counter in preferences

Comment: Just have a look at my answer it stores the day as the day of year so need to take care of 31,28,29 month issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just store the current Day of year i shared preferences and a counter of days consecutively app opened and compare the saved day in preferences on next run if day saved in shared preferences is 1 less then current day of year increment counter and save the new date and counter in preferences

just use this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int thisDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); // GET THE CURRENT DAY OF THE YEAR

        int lastDay = sharedPreferences.getInt("YOUR DATE PREF KEY", 0); //If we don't have a saved value, use 0.

        int counterOfConsecutiveDays = sharedPreferences.getInt("YOUR COUNTER PREF KEY", 0); //If we don't have a saved value, use 0.

if(lastDay == thisDay -1){
    // CONSECUTIVE DAYS
    counterOfConsecutiveDays = counterOfConsecutiveDays + 1;

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR DATE PREF KEY", thisDay);

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR COUNTER PREF KEY", counterOfConsecutiveDays).commit;
} else {

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR DATE PREF KEY", thisDay);

    sharedPreferences.edit.putInt("YOUR COUNTER PREF KEY", 1).commit();
}
```

Comment: It isn't an optimal method since user can open your app during the last day of the old year and the first day of the new year.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just store the counter -- number of days the program was opened so far and the date of last opening?

For example:
At the start counter = 0; You increase it by 1 and save the current date as 'date of last launch'.

On the next opening you just compare current date with the stored one.
If they are the same, you don't need to do anything (app was opened twice during a day), if the difference is 1 day, you just increment the counter and store new date, assuming app was opened 'counter' days in a row already + today. And if the difference is more than one, it means user has skipped at least one day, so you just need to make the counter = 1 again(current launch of the app) and store current date(starting brand new cycle).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: However, what happens if one date is the 31st and the next date is the 1st. How do I compare them?

Comment: @calum, you can store date in any format you want. Not just day.
For example, you can use unix-date. Or just store day, month and year as separate variables, or just day of year, as a number (but you should remember that 1 is the next day after 365/366). In doesn't matter.
I don't think, memory loose on storing month and year for just one date would change something.